# Возможно ли отобразить элемент QListWidgetItem на нескольких строчках?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

Имеется фиксированный `QListWidget`, некоторые его элементы не помещаются в одной строке.

Можно ли как-то отобразить текст из объекта `QListWidgetItem` на нескольких строках виджета, без управляющего символа \n?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пожалуйста, всегда предоставляйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует проблему.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class ListWidget(QListWidget):

    def resizeEvent(self, event: QResizeEvent) -> None:
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        row = 0
        while row < self.count():
            lwi_item = self.item(row)
            item_widget = self.itemWidget(lwi_item)
            if item_widget and item_widget.wordWrap():
                width_int = self.width() \
                            - self.contentsMargins().left() \
                            - self.contentsMargins().right()
                fm = self.fontMetrics()
                text_str = item_widget.text()                           
                max_rect = QRect(0, 0, width_int, 1000)
                br = fm.boundingRect(max_rect, Qt.TextWordWrap, text_str)
                
                font_br_size = br.size()
                heigth_int = font_br_size.height()
                total_height_int = heigth_int \
                                   + item_widget.contentsMargins().top() \
                                   + item_widget.contentsMargins().bottom()
                                   
                widget_size_hint = QSize(width_int, total_height_int)
                lwi_item.setSizeHint(widget_size_hint)   
            row += 1


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)        
        
        self.list_widget = ListWidget()
        self.list_widget.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.list_widget.setResizeMode(QListView.Adjust)
        self.list_widget.setUniformItemSizes(False)    
        self.list_widget.setWordWrap(True)  
        self.list_widget.setAlternatingRowColors(True)

        item_1_text_str = f"Item number 1"
        lwi_item_1 = QListWidgetItem(self.list_widget)
        self.list_widget.addItem(lwi_item_1)
        item_1_widget_qlabel = QLabel(item_1_text_str)
        item_1_widget_qlabel.setStyleSheet("*{background-color: #f0f000;}")
        self.list_widget.setItemWidget(lwi_item_1, item_1_widget_qlabel)

        item_2_text_str = f"Item number 2 - "\
            f"Возможно ли отобразить элемент QListWidgetItem на нескольких строчках?"
        lwi_item_2 = QListWidgetItem(self.list_widget)
        self.list_widget.addItem(lwi_item_2)
        item_widget_2_qlabel = QLabel(item_2_text_str)
        item_widget_2_qlabel.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, 
                                           QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        item_widget_2_qlabel.setWordWrap(True)                                     # <-------
        item_widget_2_qlabel.setStyleSheet("*{background-color: #00f0f0;}")
        lwi_item_2.setSizeHint(item_widget_2_qlabel.sizeHint())
        self.list_widget.setItemWidget(lwi_item_2, item_widget_2_qlabel)

        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit.editingFinished.connect(self.editing_finished)
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.list_widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.lineEdit.setFocus()

    def editing_finished(self):
        text = self.lineEdit.text()
        if not text:
            return
        item = QListWidgetItem(self.list_widget)
        self.list_widget.addItem(item)
        label = QLabel(text)
        label.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        label.setWordWrap(True) 
        item.setSizeHint(label.sizeHint())
        self.list_widget.setItemWidget(item, label)    
        self.lineEdit.clear()
        self.lineEdit.setFocus()
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(300, 200)
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]